# How can I put this query in the Eloquent/Laravel format?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have just one table for teams and two fields with a foreign key pointing to there.

```
DB::select('    SELECT 
                    matches.*, teams.name as home , guests.name as guest
                FROM 
                    matches
                LEFT JOIN 
                    teams
                ON 
                    teams.id = matches.home_id
                LEFT JOIN 
                    teams as guests
                ON 
                    guests.id = matches.guest_id
                ORDER BY 
                    matches.date DESC, matches.time ASC
');
```

Comment: care to post your model? or should we write our own model based on your query?

Comment: I think documentation is pretty clear on how to do this? Did you go through laravel documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```
$results = DB::table('matches')
  ->leftJoin('teams', 'teams.id', '=', 'matches.home_id')
  ->leftJoin('teams as guests', 'guests.id', '=', 'matches.guest_id')
  ->orderBy('matches.date', 'desc')
  ->orderBy('matches.time', 'asc')
  ->addSelect('matches.*', 'teams.name as home', 'guests.name as guest')
  ->get();
```